# EXCEL: How to separate words on Excel

Tags: excel

Here is an example cells

```
AED+FGH
AACDV+GFH
AFGH+ FGH
SDF+ GH
ADFG+ SDDF
HGJ+ HJ
```

If I want to separate the letters before/after the '+' - how do I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: `Text to Columns` it is on the DATA tab.

Comment: Another note.  You now have asked 3 question with answers, If any of those answers correctly answered your questions then you should mark them as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer that is correct.  If you do not do so people will stop answering your questions.  Please go back and mark the one correct answer for each of your questions, Or at least provide feedback as to why they did not work for you.

Comment: Apologies, I'm new to this website. Will do that now :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's Text to Columns, using `+` as a delimiter. That's probably the quickest way.

Select the data, then go to Data --> Text to Columns. Choose "Delimited", using a `+` delimiter. If you want, choose a destination (that's optional, you can just click "Finish" which will overwrite the current data).

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()`.

To get parts left of the `+`:

```
LEFT(A1,SEARCH("+",A1)-1)
```

and right of the `+`:

```
RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("+",A1))
```

Comment: "There's Text to Columns, using + as a delimiter. That's probably the quickest way."

Can you please elaborate on this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for this. Really helpful.